# Trying to add array elements gives zero

Tags: c++, numerical-integration, turbo-c++

So I've been trying to implement a small program to calculate double integral using simpsons 1/3 rule for a college assignment using the obsolete turbo c++ compiler (yes, we still use it!) but sadly I've seem hit a strangle glitch. Whenever I try add elements of array ax[i] in following program that gives me a zero. The elements seem to be showing up perfectly in and of themselves but adding them results in a zero for some strange reason. Here's the piece of code.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

double f(double, double);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    double a, b, c, d, h, k, ans, z[10][10], ax[10];
    int i, j, nx, ny;
    clrscr();
    a=0.0; b=1.0; c=0.0; d=1.8; h=0.25; k=0.30;
    nx = (b-a)/h;
    ny = (d-c)/k;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<10;j++)
            z[i][j] = 0;
        ax[i] = 0;
    }

    //Generating the table
    for(i=0; i<=nx; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=ny; j++)
        {
            z[i][j] = f(a+i*h, c+j*k);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<=nx; i++)
    {
        ax[i] = 0.0;

        for(j=0; j<=ny; j++)
        {
            if(j==0 || j==ny)
                ax[i] += z[i][j];
            else if(j%2==1)
                ax[i] += 4*z[i][j];
            else
                ax[i] += 2*z[i][j];
        }
        ax[i] *= k/3.0;
        cout<<ax[i]<<endl;
    }

    ans=  1.0;
    //for(int q=0; q<=nx; q++)
        ans= (ax[0])+(ax[1])+(ax[2]);


    cout<<"Value of integral is: "<<ans;
    getch();
}

double f(double x, double y)
{
    float r;
    r = 2*x*y/sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    return r;
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Did you debug or print the a[] before adding them? Is that what is behind "The elements seem to be showing up perfectly"?

Comment: Time to learn how to use the TurboC++ debugger (which was quite okay IIRC), and how to use it to step through the code line by line and looking at the values of all involved variables.

Comment: Can you tell us what output you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double f(double x, double y)
{
    float r;
    r = 2 * x*y / sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    return r;
}
```

Divides by zero when `x=0` and `y=0`, so `ax[0]` equals `nan`. When you add the numbers up, you're going to get `nan` as the output. You need to use L'Hopital's rule to evaluate that limit, and handle the first element differently.

Comment: I wonder why OP said they got `0`...

Comment: Ahan! perfect catch. Thanks. completely missed my eye.

Comment: Turbo C++ knows `NaN`?